# German Symbols in Batch

Tags: batch-file, symbols

I need to be able to ouput german symbols onto the console with, which will have to read from a txt file. currenty, whenever i try and use a batch file to output ä for exmpale, it returns o with a ~ over it. What do i need to do?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: i have tried using chcp 1252 and it doesn't seem to change anything, it still returns the same character as mentioned above

Comment: What do you use for output (echo/type ...), what do you see with the type command, eg. `type file.txt` (Umlaute?) & what codepage is installed by default (`chcp` without arguments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to define the mutations/umlaute while code page 1252 is active and switch back to 850.

```
@echo off
chcp 1252 > nul
set ae=ä
set oe=ö
set ue=ü
set sz=ß
chcp 850 > nul
echo %ae% %oe% %ue% %sz%
```

Or you edit your batch file with an editor which supports code page 850 (like notepad++).
Then you can insert directly the mutations.

Comment: Ah, maybe that's why my answer worked for me but not for the OP. I use notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to change your codepage.  I just wrote a little batch file with just `echo ä` and got the same problem you mention.  Added `chcp 1252` and it echoed the correct character.

```
chcp 1252
echo ä
```

Got the idea from here:  http://www.robvanderwoude.com/type.php#Unicode

Comment: I tried this before asking, it doesn't seem to change anything after the chcp, the character still outputs the same way.

Comment: Sorry I can't help then, that fixes it for me.  You should edit your question to indicate what you have tried.

Comment: Did you try the utf-8 codepage (`chcp 65001`)?  And/or using the Lucida console fonts?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how  Nah, never mind, on reading deeper the comments say that switching to utf-8 "breaks batch files".

Comment: See jeb's answer--I was using notepad++ when I wrote my little experiment that works on my computer.